# Silverstripe. Filtering CMS results by ID hangs

Tags: php, filter, silverstripe

I have a website built with the Silverstripe CMS.

We often have need to search for a user by their account ID.  So I added:

```
    private static $searchable_fields = array(
        'ID',
         ...
     );
```

To the Account Data Object.  When we try and search by the ID, you need to enter a hash (#) first, then the Account ID.  This seems to be the default behaviour.

When you start entering the Account ID the cpu hangs and takes a heck of a long time to respond, which makes it pointless because in the time that it takes to respond, you could just find the account by other means.  It does eventually respond and provide correct accounts that match the search terms.  None of our other search fields behave like this.

Is there a better way to implement this filter?

Comment: Firstly, adding the hash (#) is not standard behaviour so something strange is going on for sure! The ID field should always be indexed by default, but check your database has a primary field index for ID.  What version of SilverStripe are you using?  I assume you're searching in a ModelAdmin instance?  If you can show some of the code for Account that might help.

Comment: Hey Luke, yes, searching in ModelAdmin.  Using silverstripe 3.2 I believe.  I created the index and also made it a Text based search which did the trick.  Happy to accept an answer if you convert your comment into an answer.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I answered it yet!  Your solution sounds like a bit of a hack (no offence!), since something is already malfunctioning if SilverStripe didn't automatically create the ID field and its index.  Also, it's really inefficient to use a text-based search to search on a numeric column.  But perhaps I'm missing something here...  Happy to consult more if it helps.  If you're using a non-standard ID field (not the automatic DataObject.ID one), then you can use the `$indexes` static on `DataObject` to create indexes in the database.

Comment: Yeah, the ID field was already created  I don't know why it would work so hard doing a simple numerical search... But it's working now so I am happy enough.  I made it a text based search to avoid adding the #.

Comment: Okay, but be warned, if you don't look for the cause of the problem, it will probably come back to bite you later.  These two things ('#' and missing index) are indications that something is seriously wrong with your SilverStripe installation, or configuration, or code.  Best of luck, however!

Comment: Adding a an an answer in case you care to accept it still.  Regards - L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, adding the hash (#) is not standard behaviour so something strange is going on for sure! The ID field should always be indexed by default, but check your database has a primary field index for ID.
I assume you're searching in a `ModelAdmin` instance? If you can show some of the code for Account that might help.

Something is already malfunctioning if SilverStripe didn't automatically create the `ID` field and its index.

If you're using a non-standard ID field (not the automatic `DataObject.ID` one), then you can use the `$indexes` static on `DataObject` to create indexes in the database.  It's always a good idea to make sure any searched fields have indexes.
**See here:** https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/model/indexes/

Be warned, if you don't find the cause of the problem, it will probably come back to bite you later.

These two things ('#' and missing index) are indications that something is seriously wrong with your SilverStripe installation, or configuration, or code. Best of luck, however!

Comment: Thanks Luke, will look into it